# Angular4 routes not working after page refresh

Tags: angular, angular4-router

Angular 4 routes not working after page refresh. It's worked before. 
Currently when page refresh route is going to login page(default Route) it should stay on same route.

**localhost:4200/dashboard** if we refresh this page it's going to **localhost:4200/login**

I don't know whats changes is made in project suddenly it's stopped working. Please help.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "Projectname",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@aspnet/signalr-client": "^1.0.0-alpha2-final",
    "@types/signalr": "^2.2.35",
    "angular": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-datatables": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-localstorage": "^1.1.5",
    "angular-rateit": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.5.1",
    "angular-star-rating": "^3.0.8",
    "angular2-draggable": "^1.1.0-beta.0",
    "angular2-focus": "^1.1.1",
    "angular4-color-picker": "^1.4.2",
    "angular4-files-upload": "^1.0.2",
    "async": "^2.6.0",
    "auth0": "^2.9.1",
    "auth0-js": "^9.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-responsive": "^2.2.1",
    "datatables.net-responsive-dt": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.8.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-ckeditor": "^0.1.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^5.3.0",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-editor": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "ngx-rating": "0.0.9",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "^4.2.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "signalr": "^2.2.3",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Route File

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard-components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { createTemplateData } from '@angular/core/src/view/refs';
import { ErrorPageComponent } from './components/error-page/error-page.component';
import { UserLogComponent } from './Views/user-log/user-log.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
    //canLogIn:[AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'reset-password',
    component: ResetPasswordComponent
  },
  {
    path: '404',
    component: ErrorPageComponent
  },
  {
    path:'logs',
    component:UserLogComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

One more thing when i use ng serve it's showing angular cli warning.

Your global Angular CLI version (1.7.4) is greater than your local
version (1.7.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".

Comment: Show us your route file.

Comment: @Exterminator I have updated code please check

Comment: Define "doesn't work", precisely: what are you doing, what do you expect to happen, what hapens instead. Regarding the warning you get, it's self-explanatory: what don't you understand in that sentence?

Comment: there is no need of declaration in `NgModule`

Comment: @HarshitTailor what's the error you are getting when you refresh the browser? didn't find any wrong with your route config

Comment: @PratapA.K Currently when page refresh route is going to login page(default Route). it should stay on same page.

Comment: @HarshitTailor what's the url in the browser when you refresh?

Comment: @PratapA.K http://localhost:4200/dashboard  if i refresh this page its go to http://localhost:4200/login

Comment: @HarshitTailor well in that case your AuthGuard might be redirecting to login page or from your app.component.ts there might be a re-direct.

Comment: @PratapA.K I have comment out canActivate: [AuthGuard] this line but still same result.

Comment: @HarshitTailor please create stackblitz. Also please post app.component.ts, there might be a redirect from there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)
Your authguard is redirecting you to login, because you aren't logged in ( inmediatly ) on refresh.

2) About the CLI warning

In your devDependencies you have:

```
"@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
```

Globally you have installed @angular/cli@1.7.4
That's why the CLI is complaining.

If you want to keep @angular/cli@1.7.3 in your application and avoid the warning you can do what's mentioned:

```
ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false
```

Or install the same version globally

```
npm i -g @angular/cli@1.7.3
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have comment out canActivate: [AuthGuard] this line from route but still getting same result.